# Why is the term instantaneous work not defined?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

I was reading a textbook and found the statement that said that there is no such term as instantaneous work, however the textbook does not give a reason as to why it cannot be defined. To me it sounds perfectly fine to define instantaneous work for particles where force applied remains constant as
$\vec{dF}*\vec{s}$  and if this was not enough many derivations in physics regarding energy do seem to use the term ${dW}$ so what is the problem with instantaneous work?

Comment: it would be useful to quote the book

Comment: Was this a JEE prep book?

Comment: @knzhou Yes indeed it was a JEE Prepbook

Comment: @jim The book was Cengage Mechanics for JEE Advanced.

Comment: JEE books are famous on this site for having lots of confusing and not quite correct statements. If you ever have a doubt reading one, you should probably just assume it’s wrong.

Comment: I’ve personally flipped through the Cengage books and they’re incredibly confusing, don’t know how anybody can learn anything with them…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do nonzero work you must apply nonzero force across nonzero distance. To speak of something instantaneous you must do it in time $\Delta t \to 0$. To cross nonzero distance in time $\Delta t \to 0$ one needs $v \to \infty$. There is no infinite velocity therefore there is no instantaneous work.

---

Another way to look at it.

Instantaneous work asks, "How much work is being done *right now*?" to which the answer is always 0, because *right now* precludes movement in space and time.

We can still use $dW$ to ask questions about "What happens when an infinitesimal amount of work is done?" Because when any work is done something must have moved through space and time, one answer to that question is always "some time passes".

So not only can we use use $dW$ even though there is no instantaneous work, we actually need $dW$ in order to mathematically define the nonexistence of nonzero instantaneous work:

$$\frac{dt}{dW} \neq 0$$

---

Since $\frac{dt}{dW}$ is nonzero, the inverse, $\frac{dW}{dt}$ is defined. This is Power, the instantaneous rate of work mentioned by Dale in the comment below.

So, while the answer to "How much work is being done *right now*?" is always 0, there are many possibilities for the question "Right now, *how fast* are we doing work?"

Comment: You may want to mention power which is the instantaneous *rate* of work

Comment: So to just make sure I am grasping it right the only reason why ${dW}$ is not defined is because if we do want it to be defined then we have to force ${ds}$ to be non-zero instantaneously which means $\frac{\vec{ds}}{dt}$ which is $ \vec{v}$ must approach $\infty$ . But we can still use $\frac{dW}{dt}$ as both the numerator and denominator approach 0 leading to a indeterminate. So in one sense it is wrong to say instantaneous work  is not defined, but instead say it is 0 at the instant.

Comment: Rate of change of work with respect to time (Power) can be as big as you want but never infinite, and rate of change of time with respect to work can be as little as you want, but never zero.

Comment: As to whether instantaneous work is zero or undefined, I would call it 0, not undefined, but I wouldn't stake my reputation to it.

Answer (score 0):

One may consider an instant work $E(t)$ as a work done up to the current instant $t$ from $t=0$.