# Energy conservation or work-energy theorem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, spring

[image]

Let's assume a block of mass $m$ is allowed to go down from rest on an inclined plane. There is a spring at the bottom on the inclined plane with inclination $\theta$ as shown in the figure. We want to know how much the spring will be compressed($x$) by the block.

I will present two thought processes and want to know if either of them is wrong.

1. As there is no external force in this system,the mechanical energy will be preserved. Initial mechanical energy of the object is $mg(h+x)\sin \theta$. The final mechanical energy will be $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$. Hence our equation is $mg(h+x)\sin \theta=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$.

Now,the second one on which i am confused mostly.

2. Work done by gravity on the block is $mg(h+x)\sin \theta$. Work done by spring on the block is $-\frac{1}{2}kx^2$. *Initial* and *final* kinetic energies both are zero. Hence from Work Energy Theorem, $mg(h+x)\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$.

Though the equation came out to be the correct one in the work energy theorem method, i have a few doubts on this as i explained in my previous post
[Conditions of work-energy theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/724963/)

Here, we can see that gravity was acting from the very beginning but spring force did work using spring force only when the block started touching the spring. So there is time difference between the forces. Also i took initial and final velocities as $0$ since they look like those even though these two words are still vague to me in the theorem. Nevertheless,this method ended up giving me the correct answer. I thought illustrating my doubt with a problem will be very helpful. So, i created a new post with a problem based on that.

Comment: could you show the math explaining "  Initial and final kinetic energies both are zero. Hence from Work Energy Theorem"?   that isn't how I would do it. i would say $mgh \sin(\theta)+  mg\Delta x \sin(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} k (\Delta x)^2 $ because all the work exerted by gravity goes into the compression of the spring. i don't follow the kinetic energy argument.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be focusing on "time" a force is applied.  Potential and Kinetic Energy (the only types relevant here) are state variables, meaning their values depend only on the initial and final states, not on the path it took to get there, or how much time passed from one to the other.  E.g. you can slowly lower that block from the top to the bottom of the ramp over 1 year, or do it in 1 second, and the potential energy lost will still be $mgh$.

So energy in this case is a state variable.  Now work is simply the difference between two energy states:

$$W = E_2 - E_1$$

Time does not come into play here at all.

In your example, the initial state is

$1)$ block is at a height of $h$; spring is uncompressed

The associated energy of State 1 is:

$$E_1 = E_{grav} + E_{spring} \\ = mgh + 0 \\ = mgh$$

The new state of the system, State 2 (without saying anything about how it came to be) is:

$2)$ block is at a height of $-x\sin(\theta)$; spring is compressed by $x$

The associated energy of State 2 is:

$$E_2 = E_{grav} + E_{spring} \\ = -mgx\sin(\theta) + 0.5kx^2 $$

Now, to find the work required to move from State 1 to State 2:

$$W = E_2-E_1 \\ =(-mgx\sin(\theta)-mgh)+(0.5kx^2-0) \\ =-mg(x\sin(\theta)+h)+0.5kx^2
$$

Note that the first term (gravity work) and second term (spring work) are opposite in sign, because the former is spontaneous (block falls with gravity) whereas the compressing of the spring is forced (spring is fighting against the block).

These two sources of energy change (gravity and spring) were treated totally independently, and it did not matter if they acted separately or at the same time.  The initial and final states are all that matter.

(Caveat: this is all true for what are called *conservative* forces or force fields, i.e. those that can be defined by a potential energy.  Dissipative forces like friction also do work and change the energy of an object, but they do depend on the path taken.)

Answer (score 2):

The two approaches are equally valid (under the further stipulation below). As I said in my answer to your previous post, the timing of the forces is irrelevant provided you specify the initial and final state, which in this case you did.

That said, application of conservation of mechanical energy requires that there are no internal dissipative (friction) forces in the system, whereas the work energy theorem does not.

In your example if the plane was not frictionless the total mechanical KE + PE would not be conserved. For the work energy theorem you would add the negative work done by friction to the negative work done by the spring and positive work done by gravity for a net work of zero.

To sum up the last point, the work energy theorem takes into account the work done by both conservative and non conservative (e.g. friction) forces, whereas the principle of conservation of mechanical energy only applies to the work done by conservative forces (e.g., gravity and the ideal spring force).

Hope this helps.